# ...lib/crt1.o: In function `_start': (.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main' with IDL6.2

Tags: linux, gcc, idl

I am trying to build an old program using IDL6.2 in CentOS7, which was originally built for RHEL3 and runs in RHEL5.
However, when I try to make it in CentOS7, I get the error bellow.
May that be an compatibility problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks!

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
XXX.o: In function `XXX(std::string const&)':
XXX.h:204: undefined reference to `IDL_Message'
XXX.o: In function `XXX(int, IDL_VARIABLE**)':
XXX.cpp:217: undefined reference to `IDL_MessageVE_REQSTR'
XXX.cpp:218: undefined reference to `IDL_MessageVE_REQSTR'
XXX.cpp:271: undefined reference to `IDL_GettmpInt'
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116399/crt1-o-in-function-start-undefined-reference-to-main-in-linux ?

Comment: @EdmCoff Yes, I can't find that LINK statement in my makefile. But that raises me a question of whether it appears in the previous versions that work... Monday is coming and I will check that!

Comment: @EdmCoff Monday came, I compared the two makefiles and I did not get to a solution...

Comment: Are the RHEL systems 32-bit and the CentOS system 64-bit?

Comment: They were both 64-bit. Nevertheless, I found the problem... It was because of incompatibilities between the versions of Automake (1.13.4 and 1.9.6). Thank you @EdmCoff anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the root of the problem! Incompatibility of Automake between the versions 1.9 (in RHEL5) and 1.13 in (CentOS7).